# XML Reader Variables VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, listview, textbox, xmlreader

Working on a management program for basic files and text.

Now, so far the program is saving information from multiple textboxes into an .xml file correctly.

My problem is where I need to load saved files back into Textboxes.
Here is [another thread I made to Microsoft explaining my issue;](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/471a022c-ab75-431c-82c1-cb1e7746e9c3/how-can-i-load-the-selected-xml-file-selected-from-a-listview-into-the-correct-textboxes?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Right, so the code I currently have and use;

```
Private Sub Objectlist1_ItemActivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Objectlist1.ItemActivate
    Caseworker.Show() 
    Me.Objectlist1.MultiSelect = False

    Dim selectedListViewItem As String
    selectedListViewItem = Me.Objectlist1.SelectedItems.Item(0).ToString

    If (IO.File.Exists(selectedListViewItem + "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Testfolder-data")) Then
        Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(selectedListViewItem + "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Testfolder-data")

        While (document.Read())
            Dim type = document.NodeType

            If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then
                If (document.Name = "Person") Then
                    Caseworker.Pholderbox.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()
                End If

                If (document.Name = "Driver") Then
                    Caseworker.Driverbox.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()
```

Problem here is that I want to be able to click a file in the Listview called "Objectlist1" and the program loads the xml file - Instead of directing the program to One file

As such

```
If (IO.File.Exists("MyXML.xml")) Then
    Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader("MyXML.xml)
```

Apparently there is this variable out there that would be perfect for my issue, but I have looked for it for 2 working days and not been able to track it down.

If there is another stuff I need to add to make this thing work, I appreciate any help you can provide.

Am I far off here guys?

Comment: What do you expect `(selectedListViewItem + "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Testfolder-data")` to be? (Hint: did you mean `Path.Combine("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Testfolder-data",selectedListViewItem )`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

You need the full path to the XMLFile, not just its name. You could do it like this (warning: untested):

```
const string basepath= @"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Testfolder-data"

xmlpath = IO.Path.Combine(basepath, Objectlist1.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text)
If(IO.File.Exists(xmlpath))
```

Instead of multiple Ifs, I would recommend

```
switch(document.Name)
  {
      Case "Person":
        Caseworker.Pholderbox.Text=...
        break;

      Case "Driver":
      ...
  }
```

If you rename "Pholderbox" to "Personbox", you could spare the entire If/switch and simply do something like:

```
var textbox = document.name + "box";
(TextBox)Caseworker.Controls[textbox].Text=document.InnerText;
```

Hope this gets you going.

Comment: I knew this was the right place to ask!
Right, I am seeing what you are thinking and doing with that code, which is going to help me understand my issue. So I am grateful for that.
Further more, I seem to be running into a identifier issue on this code
<code>
const string basepath= @"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Testfolder-data"
</code> As "string" is being marked as error, and telling me that the Keyword is not valid as identifier. Have I forgot to Imports anything?
Am I placing this code in the wrong Sub?
I've placed it both in the Form1_Load and also in Objectlist1.ItemActivate

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I wrote in C# but what you need is VB of course!
Should instead be: Const basepath as String = @"..."

Comment: Thank you good Sir, that one worked much better in the terms of basepath!

Is it still right of me to Dim xmlpath = IO.Path ect ect?
Without the "Dim" part I get red lines telling me to declare.

Comment: I consider this Post Closed as you have resolved my issue and also helped a little on the side.
I have permissionscrap to fix now, but that has nothing to do with the previous codes. Its just this Windows being an arse.

Thank you fine Sir!